# Output in a table like format is not lining up

Tags: c++

Here is what my output looks like: 
[image]

i would like to have the output in a  nice table like format with headers and the data in the middle of the setw area alloted for that variable. Im not sure how to go about doing this.

Code:

```
/***************************************************/
/* Author:     Sam LaManna                         */
/* Course:     CSC 135 Lisa Frye                   */
/* Assignment: Program 4 Grade Average             */
/* Due Date:   10/10/11                            */
/* Filename:   program4.cpp                        */
/* Purpose:    Write a program that will process   */
/*             students are their grades. It will  */
/*             also read in 10 test scores and     */
/*             compute their average               */
/***************************************************/

#include <iostream>     //Basic input/output
#include <iomanip>      //Manipulators
#include <string>       //String stuff 
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void instruct ();       //Function declaration for printing instructionstring studname ();
void input (ifstream &infile, float& test1, float& test2, float& test3, float& test4, float& test5, float& test6, float& test7, float& test8, float& test9, float& test10, string& studentname);      //Function declaration for input
float aver (float test1, float test2, float test3, float test4, float test5, float test6, float test7, float test8, float test9, float test10);      //Function declaration for calculating average
void output (string studentname, float average);      //Function declaration for output



int main()
{
  float test1 = 0;              //Vars (test1 - test10) for test scores
  float test2 = 0;
  float test3 = 0;
  float test4 = 0;
  float test5 = 0;
  float test6 = 0;
  float test7 = 0;
  float test8 = 0;
  float test9 = 0;
  float test10 = 0;
  string studentname = "a";     //Define Var for storing students name
  float average = 0;            //Define var for storing average


  instruct();     //Function call to print instructions


  ifstream infile("grades.dat");

  input (infile, test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, test8, test9, test10, studentname);     //Function call for scores

  cout << left;
  cout << setw (30) << "Student Name" << setw (5)<< "Average" << setw (12) << "Letter Grade" << "\n";     //headers for output  

  while (!infile.eof())
    {
      average = aver (test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, test8, test9, test10);    //Function call for average

      output (studentname, average);     //Function call for output


      input (infile, test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, test8, test9, test10, studentname); //Get new input
    }     //end eof

  return 0;
}

/***************************************************/
/* Name: instruct                                  */
/* Description: Print instructions to user.        */
/* Paramerters: N/A                                */
/* Return Value: N/A                               */
/***************************************************/

void instruct()
{
  cout << "\n" << "This program will calculate the average of 10 test scores that are read from a file. " << "\n" << "\n";
  //Prints instructions

  return;
}

/***************************************************/
/* Name: input                                     */
/* Description: Get input                          */
/* Paramerters: N/A                                */
/* Return Value: N/A                               */
/***************************************************/

void input (ifstream& infile, float& test1, float& test2, float& test3, float& test4, float& test5, float& test6, float& test7, float& test8, float& test9, float& test10, string& studentname)

{
  getline(infile, studentname);
  infile >> test1 >> test2 >> test3 >> test4 >> test5 >> test6 >> test7 >> test8 >> test9 >> test10;
  infile.ignore(10, '\n');

  return;
}



/***************************************************/
/* Name: aver                                      */
/* Description: Calculate Average                  */
/* Paramerters: N/A                                */
/* Return Value: aver                              */
/***************************************************/


float aver (float test1, float test2, float test3, float test4, float test5, float test6, float test7, float test8, float test9, float test10)

{
  float aver = 0;
  aver = test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + test5 + test6 + test7 + test8 + test9 + test10;
  aver = aver / 10;
  return aver;
}


/***************************************************/
/* Name: output                                    */
/* Description: Calculate Average                  */
/* Paramerters: N/A                                */
/* Return Value: aver                              */
/***************************************************/

void output (string studentname, float average)      //Function declaration for output
{
  char letter = 'Z';

  if (( average < 101) && (average > 89.9))
    {letter = 'A';
    }
  else if (( average < 90) && (average > 79.9))
      {letter = 'B';
      }
  else if (( average < 80) && (average > 69.9))
    {letter = 'C';
    }
  else if (( average < 70) && (average > 59.9))
      {letter = 'D';
      }
  else if ((average < 60) && (average > -1))
        {letter = 'F';
        }
  else if (average >100)
    {
      letter = 'A';
    }
  else 
    {cout << "Error, Program shutting down.";
      exit (0);
    }

  cout << left;

  cout << setw (30) << studentname << setw (5) << setprecision (2)<< fixed << average << setw (12) << letter << "\n";

  return;
}
```

Comment: The image is compressed, making the text very illegible.

Comment: Kshitij Mehta, to see the image in a more legible format, you can right click on the image and select view image. The image is now the sole item in your browser, at that point you can then click on it again for it to increase its magnification. Another click will cause the magnification to decrease.

Comment: @KshitijMehta: Ctrl+<mousewheel up>

Comment: One suggestion if you insist on posting screenshots, crop the image to the relevant area, here something like 80% of the image has no meaningful use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cout << setw (30) << "Student Name" << setw (5)<< "Average" << setw (12) << "Letter Grade" << "\n";     //headers for output

cout << setw (30) << studentname << setw (5) << setprecision (2)<< fixed << average << setw (12) << letter << "\n";

I don't know much about c++, but this is what appears to be going on.  That setw function is some sort of width, and in your header, you only have 5 spaces for the word average, which already messes up the output considering the number of letters in the word itself.  Try changing setw(5) in both cases above to something like setw (15) and see what that looks like.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

I find the information at this page (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/iomanip.html) a great reminder for `setw()` usage.

Aside from that, Mike_K, is correct. You've specified a width of 5 characters for the 'Average' column (7 characters).

To make it easier to see how the values impact the output, you might consider doing something like:

```
// these three values are globals
const unsigned int NAME_LEN(30);
const unsigned int AVG_LEN(10);
const unsigned int GRADE_LEN(12);
...
...
  cout << setw (NAME_LEN) << "Student Name" << setw (AVG_LEN)<< "Average"
       << setw (GRADE_LEN) << "Letter Grade" << "\n";     //headers for output
```

Where you use the global values for each of your `cout` statements.  That way if you wanted to see what it would look like if you change the length of the average column from 10 to 20, you could change the value once, recompile and re-run. I find it easier to change the value in one location rather than in multiple locations

Granted, others may argue with the usage of global variables.